# How to keep a coroutine running after a screen (Activity/Fragment) is closed in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, coroutinescope

`Activity` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val vm = getViewModel<MyViewModel>()
        vm.invoke()
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.getViewModel(): T {
    return ViewModelProvider(this)[T::class.java]
}
```

The code in my `ViewModel` class looks like the following:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: Repository = Repository()
 
    fun invoke() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.execute()
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
private class Repository {
    suspend fun execute() {
        val isSuccess = libraryFunction()
        if (isSuccess) {
            onSuccess()
        }
    }

    suspend fun onSuccess() {
        Log.d("Repo", "onSuccess called")
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

Function from a library that can't be modified:

```
private val someItems = listOf("1", "2", "3")

suspend fun libraryFunction(): Boolean = coroutineScope {
    someItems.map { item ->
        async {
            processItem(item)
        }
    }.awaitAll()
    true
}
    
suspend fun processItem(item: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    delay(5000) // simulate processing
}
```

When `Activity`/`Fragment` is closed before `onSuccess()` is executed the log

```
onSuccess called
```

isn't printed in the Logcat.

In some situations I need to execute `onSuccess()` function even if `Activity`/`Fragment` is closed before.

Is it possible to do it without using `GlobalScope`, `Service` and `WorkManager` classes?

Comment: I think GlobalScope is the appropriate tool for this. Or you can create your own CoroutineScope to use for these kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you described, related to the coroutine scope.
You are using `ViewModelScope` when launching coroutine:

> A ViewModelScope is defined for each ViewModel in your app. Any
> coroutine launched in this scope is automatically canceled if the
> ViewModel is cleared. Coroutines are useful here for when you have
> work that needs to be done only if the ViewModel is active. For
> example, if you are computing some data for a layout, you should scope
> the work to the ViewModel so that if the ViewModel is cleared, the
> work is canceled automatically to avoid consuming resources.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope

You can use `GlobalScope` or some other.
Details about coroutine's scope you can find here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scopes-in-kotlin-coroutines/